# Selecting Flex chart items and displaying sum of items selected

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, charts

I would like to use the selectionMode=multiple described in the [Flex docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=charts_eventsandeffects_12.html), but with a few modifications:

1) I would like the box that the user drags over the graph to remain there until the user drags a new one.

2) In the top right corner of the box I want to display the sum of the items selected by that box.

Does anyone have any examples of this or something similar?

If not, what's the easiest way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this
http://demo.quietlyscheming.com/ChartSampler/app.html